# Modifying an Existing PDF without creating an new pdf file

Tags: java, itext

Using iText, I am wanting to open a PDF file, add some more pages with text to it, and then close it. I have found some questions like this on here, but all require creating a new PDF file. Is there any way to read in the pdf file and modify it and then overwrite the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can create a new pdf file, and afterwards overwriting the old file with the new one.

[Commons Apache File Util](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

```
forceDelete(oldPdf)
moveFile(newPdf, oldPdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can always overwrite a file (if it is not locked by the OS) by writing to the whole content to the `FileOutputStream`. You cannot partially write to part of a file unless it is to append data at the end of file. This is limited by the operating system itself so there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I haven't worked much with files.